# NameError: global name 'hello' is not defined Python

Tags: python

Hi im trying to learn Python and have a err i can understand ,

```
[Call.py]
CODE:
-------------------------------------
def intro():
    print "Function Works !";
------------------------------------

ERROR:
-------------------------
into();
NameError: name 'into' is not defined
[Finished]
-------------------------------


[main.py]

CODE:
-------------------------
import call

# Do Some Stuff
call();

-----------------------

ERROR:
------------------------
into();
NameError: name 'into' is not defined
-----------------------
[Finished]
```

Comment: I am mystified why people would write correct answers as comments.. More rep for the rest of us! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined a function named `intro`, and then tried to invoke it as `into`.  Choose one name and stick with it.

UPDATE:  if you have a function named `intro` in call.py, then after `import call`, you need to invoke it as `call.intro()`.

Comment: A further note: Python is case sensitive, so you'll also have to watch for `Intro` vs. `intro`. If in doubt, stick with the [established naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @user1478869: then you need to post the actual code.  Also, get rid of the semicolons...

Comment: im scripting php thats why i using the semicolons ... im write them automatic without thinkin about it :/